# Apache как кэширующий прокси с определённых адресов

Tags: apache

Есть Apache (2.2.17 win32) в локальной сети, который работает веб-сервером. Как его настроить как кэширующий прокси-сервер (через mod_proxy) с возможностью кэшировать данные только с определенных доменов?

Пытался определять нужные домены `<ProxyMatch (domain1|domain2)\.ru>`, далее в этот тег вставить

```
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
    <IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
        CacheRoot cache
        CacheEnable disk /
        CacheMinFileSize 1
        CacheMaxFileSize 2000000
        CacheDirLevels 4
        CacheDirLength 4
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

но так не выходит, куда копать?

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую Вам использовать Apache, как веб сервер, а [Squid](http://squid.opennet.ru/) как кэширующий прокси.

Comment: Вместе они отлично работают.

Comment: да, спасибо, про сквид знаю.
   
хотелось бы найти решение на апаче, т.к. машина нагружена и без того

Comment: Тогда посмотрите http://www.lissyara.su/articles/freebsd/programms/apache_2.2_as_proxy/. Здесь не про win, но смысл в этом есть.

Comment: А вот это http://www.linuxcenter.ru/lib/articles/networking/apache_proxy.phtml точно работает, только что проверил.